# QT Creator easier "contexthelp"

Tags: qt-creator

I just started using the QT Creator but there's some stuff that really annoys me...

I like that i can show the coding window and the context help window next to each other.
But the shortcut for showing the context help for the currently selected Symbol is F1, which is just terrible as Mac-User @_@

Now it would be nice if I could either put in on alt+"left mouse button".
What would be even better is, if i select a word with the mouse and it's a QT-Object like QSlider, to automatically change the content of the help window to the selected word.

Any help on that matter? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can customise the Keyboard short-cuts in Qt Creator:

1. Open the **Options** dialog (on Windows, it's via Tools->Options - I presume it'll be somewhere different on a Mca)
2. In the **Environment** page, select the **Keyboard** tab.
3. Scroll down to the **Help** section, and change the setting on the **Context** command from F1 to whatever you want it to be.

This should go some way to making it easier for you to use.

**Edit**

If you want to make wider changes, you could always import a .kms QtCreator keyboard definitions file that someone else has created. For example, searching for 'qt creator kms' points to:

- [TextMate key mapping scheme for Qt Creator](https://github.com/wimleers/qt-creator-textmate-kms)
- [XCode Keyboard Mapping for Qt Creator](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/0b13357700af401a187fdf34c7e0f7831844c9ab/share/qtcreator/schemes/Xcode.kms)

Comment: yeah, problem is that there aren't really any keys left... only finger-cramping combinations of about 3 keys :/
still thx

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I just added another suggestion above - with links to Mac-like keyboard definitions files...